# extract java maven project component as separate project

Tags: java, maven, project-management, maven-3

I'm new to Maven, and decided to start with it on a project I started to develop recently. The project is a Java library that parses unit conversion queries written in natural language, and performs the unit conversion that was interpreted out of the natural language query.

For this project I needed an inflection library for Java (pluralize/singularize words), and after pondering some options I decided to develop my own. It turns out that there have been some interest from some people in using this inflection functionality **alone**.

So the question is, **what would be the best approach to split off the classes providing inflection functionality (which are in a separate package within my unit conversion project) into a separate new Maven project, publish this inflection library in some sort of public Maven repository, and specify it as a dependency of my unit conversion library**. This way, anybody else wanting to use the inflection library would be able to do so by putting it as dependency of their own projects.

Note that my question includes the part of "publishing one's library in a Maven repo so that it can be a dependency of other projects". I am totally new to Maven so I really haven't grasped the whole thing. I merely limit myself to set up the dependencies of my own project, build, run, etc.

Comment: Just in case it matters, I'm using netbeans and git, and the project in question is published on github. I would like to split off the inflection functionality into a new Maven project that would also be published on github, but still have it available as a maven dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Open Source:

- Make the source code available, e.g. at sourceforge.net
- Make sure your POM inherits (directly or indirectly) from:

:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
  </parent>
```

- Perform a Maven release to deploy to Maven Central: follow the steps at: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-9.StageaRelease

For Closed Source:

- Setup a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus

  - Make sure the public group is available to the target audience
- Configure the Maven release plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/

General recommendations:

- For the package name start with the reverse domain name, eg.

  - org.myproject.mycomponent (if you have a custom domain for this project)
  - com.mycompany.myproject.mycomponet (if your company owns the domain mycompany.com)
  - net.sourceforge.myproject.mycomponent (if you host your source code at myproject.sourceforge.net and don't have a custom domain)
- groupId:

  - Use the start of the package name such as com.mycompany.myproject
  - Usually use the same groupId for all Maven project inside a single VCS repository
- artifactId: make sure it is unique enough as it will be the start of the file name of the jar, e.g. mycompany-myproject-mycomponent
- Setup a CI server such as Jenkins

  - Make sure the CI server is run by a dedicated system user
  - Add the necessary credentials to the settings.xml file of the CI user
  - Configure a job for "clean install"
  - Configure a job for releasing the library (Jenkins has a special plugin to support Maven releases)
- Consider to turn your jar into an OSGi bundle